# How do I stop automatic stretching of the other axis for instances when stretching one of its axis?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When applying code for a laser weapon projectile (an instance of the laser beam itself) which would enable the laser to to act similarly to that of a real one, I had everything working great... except for the fact that the projectile kept stretching in the y axis as well as the x axis, instead of just the x axis. Now, I've found out that something like scaleMode needs to be disabled, but the best I've found is a line of code that goes like "stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;", which is meant for the stage and not instances themselves and if I tried to apply something like this for an ADDED event within the laser beam's class code I get error 1120 saying . Here is the code I think is necessary to present here from the beam's class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    public class weapon3projectileCode extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _root:Object;
        public function weapon3projectileCode()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED, beginClass);
        }
        private function beginClass(event:Event):void
        {
            _root = MovieClip(root);
            this.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            this.scaleX = .25;
            this.scaleY = .2;
        }
        private function entFrame(event:Event):void
        {
            if (_root.gamePaused == false)
            {
                x += speed;
                if (stretchWhile < stretchTill)
                {
                    this.width += 25;
                    this.x = _root.playerShip.x;
                    this.y = _root.playerShip.y;
                }
                else if (stretchWhile < shrinkTill)
                {
                    this.width -= 25;
                }
                else if (stretchWhile >= shrinkTill)
                {
                    this.width = .25;
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, entFrame);
                    _root.projectilePlayerContainer.removeChild(this);
                }
                stretchWhile ++;
                if(this.x > (stage.width+ this.width))
                {
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, entFrame);
                    _root.projectilePlayerContainer.removeChild(this);
                }
            }
            if (_root.removeProjectiles == true)
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, entFrame);
                _root.projectilePlayerContainer.removeChild(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No scalemode does not need to be disabled. Just adjust the scaleX value of the instance. Are the lasers always just going left and right horizontally, or can they rotate to other directions? If so, you'll need to just scale the laser, but have the laser be in a container that rotates. If your rotate the laser, the x axis will change. But if you don't rotate the laser, and instead rotate its parent, it will work.

Comment: When you adjust the width in your stretch code, this should work fine as long as the laser is horizontal. If the angle of the laser is up or down from that, when you scale the width up, it is not adjusting the scaleY value, but you are exposing some of relative height of the laser to the x axis itself.

Comment: That's strange, because I tried this.width as well as this.scaleX and in BOTH scenarios the Y axis or horizontal stretch was increasing along with the x axis/width. And no, none of these two are rotating. But lets say I do need to disable scalemode for the laser beam specifically, how would I do that?

Comment: you can't disable scaleMode for a movie clip.  That is a property of the stage/app/root/parentWindow etc.  Can you post a picture of what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You should specifically alter `scaleX` instead of `width`. You need to have your laser drawn by say 100 pixels long and say 10 pixels wide (to taste), then once you determine the desired distance of your laser, you set its `scaleX` to `desiredWidth/100`, this should eliminate your laser scaling by Y.

Comment: Nope, it still increases the laser's Y axis. Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that it's a tiny red sphere with an orange outline drawn with flash tools before it gets scaled? Regardless, it doesn't seem like scaling down scaleY while scalingX will keep scaleY from being scaled up, so I think I really need that scale mode to be gotten rid of for this specific instance.

Comment: Please edit your question with entire code that's altering your laser MC, probably you still have some assignment to width or height in there somewhere.

Comment: @XirmiX is this like a first-person shooter (the circle is for target aiming)? If instead you mean a beam that shoots like a straight line then use a growing **rectangle** shape not a stretched **circle**.

Comment: I think I've mentioned this multiple times that I'm working on a simple side-scrolling shooter. With a rectangle, the same thing happens; Y axis is being stretched along with the X axis.

Comment: Never mind, I got the laser working. Seems pretty annoyingly dumb that just because it's a circle, both its axes must expand if one expands. Same goes for if you draw a line, but a rectangle works just fine and now I have a proper laser working, thanks :)